# How to Upgrade to 15.04 without upgrading to 14.10?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 15.04

I would like to upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04 from Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. I went in the terminal, edited the `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` file, and set the prompt to normal. I went back into the terminal, and ran the command `sudo do-release-upgrade -c`, and this is the output:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release

New release '14.10' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

How can I upgrade to 15.04 without going to 14.10?

Comment: You can not. You can upgrade from LTS to LTS but you can not skip releases in between if you are not upgrading to LTS. 15.04 is not LTS.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It makes no difference either way.

Comment: Because it seems time consuming to upgrade twice instead of upgrading straight to 15.04

Comment: Fresh install is always faster then an upgrade.